# python-tesseract OCR: get digits only

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm using tesseract OCRwith python-tesseract.
In the [tesseract FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ), regarding digits, we have:

> Use
>
> `TessBaseAPI::SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");`
>
> BEFORE calling an Init function or put this in a text file called
>   tessdata/configs/digits:
>
> `tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789`
>
> and then your command line becomes:
>
> `tesseract image.tif outputbase nobatch digits`
>
> Warning: Until the old and new config variables get merged, you must
>   have the nobatch parameter too.

In python-tesseract, the SetVariable method exists. I've tried this, but the result of the OCR is the same:

```
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789")
api.Init('.','eng',tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)
```

Did anyone already got this working, or should I consider it a bug in python-tesseract?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, got it working.
According to this [(unofficial ?) documentation](http://fossies.org/dox/tesseract-3.01/classtesseract_1_1TessBaseAPI.html#a2e09259c558c6d8e0f7e523cbaf5adf5) of tesseract-ocr, SetVariable() must be called after Init(), even though the opposite is said in the official FAQ.
Calling it after Init() works as intended.